# Problem for delete character added by mask

Tags: javascript, html, regex, mask, adonis.js

I'm a junior developer and in charge of implementing some masks for inputs in customer web application. I already implement the function that made the mask, but the functions has a problem, I can't delete the characters added by the mask. Someone knows what's wrong?

The function are the same but just the regex changes.

The input

```
<input required type="tel" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="(99) 99999-9999" class="input border-white placeholder-gray input-ghost focus:bg-white focus:text-accent" onfocus="sss()" pattern="[(][0-9]{2}[)] [0-9]{5}-[0-9]{4}" />
```

```
<input required type="text" placeholder="XX. XXX. XXX/0001-XX" name="cnpj" maxlength="18" id="cnpj" class="input border-white placeholder-gray input-ghost focus:bg-white focus:text-accent"/ onfocus="test()">
```

The masks

Phone mask

```
<script\>
document.getElementById('telefone').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
var x = e.target.value.replace(/\\D/g, '').match(/(\\d{0,2})(\\d{0,5})(\\d{0,4})/);
e.target.value = '(' +x\[1\] + ') '+ x\[2\] + '-' + x\[3\]
});
function sss()
{
console.log(document.getElementById('telefone').value)
}
\</script\>
```

Interprises IDs mask

```
<script>
 document.getElementById('cnpj').addEventListener('input', function(e){
    var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,2})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})(\d{0,2})/);
    e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : x[1] + '.' + x[2] + '.' + x[3] + '/' + x[4] + (x[5] ? '-' + x[5] : '');
  })
</script>
```

I tried to add "?" on the regex sentence but didn't work

Comment: Can you give an example of the input/output you are expecting?

Comment: for the phone: input = xxxxxxxxxxx/ output = (xx)xxxxx-xxxx
For the enterprises ID's: input: XXXXXXXX0001XX / output = XX. XXX. XXX/0001-XX
When x is some number.

Comment: But the problem is, the output is working. But if i try to delete what's in the input the characters ".", "/", "-" and "()"  can't be deleted